# Process messages from different inbounds in the same thread

Tags: spring-integration

I have two inbound-channel-adapter which collect files from two distinct sources.

I'd like to process the incoming files one at a time, by the same instance of service-activator and in the same thread. At the moment, since there are two distinct Poller, they are actually processed by two different threads concurrently.

I thought that using a queueChannel to feed my service-activator would have solved the problem but I don't want to introduce another Poller (and hence, another delay).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ExecutorChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) with an `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

You can also use a `QueueChannel` with a `fixedDelay` of 0; the poller blocks in the queue for 1 second by default (and can be increased - `receiveTimeout`) so with a 0 delay between polls, no additional latency will be added.